# Visual Studio 2013 can't run c# files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've recently downloaded vs 2013, and when I hit Start(with or without debugging) when working on console applications the Error is :

```
Error   1   Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs' could not be found

+path of the project
```

What can I do? I tried to repair the .net framework on my computer but it's still the same.

Comment: That is not a valid path. You sure a config / proeject file isn't messed up? Open your project file in notepad and take a look.

Comment: Your machine setup is borken, c:\windows\temp is no longer a suitable directory to store temporary files.  Ask at superuser.com how to fix this.

Comment: This kind of error appeared in correct setup too (C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\.NetFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttribute.cs) too.  Changing the project's Target Framework to .Net 4.5.1, solved the issue to me.

Comment: This happened to me when I rename a project folder and recreated one with the same name with VS 2013 on Win7. My solution: (1) DELETE or move  the renamed old project folder from the web server; (2) Run VS and open the project, clean solution and build solution; (3) This should work. If it does NOT work, use CCleaner to clean windows temparary files;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This link suggests that you have trouble writing to the temp directory.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73e67f3a-c575-4c73-a71d-ed7a2aeabb50/csc-error-cs2001-source-file-cwindowstempnetframeworkversionv40assemblyattributescs?forum=msbuild

Grant permissions read/write/execute to the temp folder, or maybe try running visual studio as administrator to see if it is permissions related.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not installed .net4.5 yet.

[.net4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)